# Как использовать переменную VueJs внутри переменной Jinja2?

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, jinja2

Конфликт разделителей Jinja2 и VueJS решается очень просто:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  },
  delimiters: ['[[',']]']
})
```

Т.е. теперь можно так:

```
  <div id="app">
      {{normaltemplatetag}}
      [[ message ]] 
    </div>
```

Но у меня проблема в другом. Как мне внутри `{{ }}` использовать `[[ ]]` как переменную VueJS? Это нужно, например, при генерации поля формы:

```
{{ form.field(id='index-blabla-' + [[index]], placeholder="Бла бла", **{'v-model':'form.field'}) }}
```

В данном случае `[[index]]` jinja определяет как список:

```
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Хотелось бы, например, написать так:

```
{{ form.field(id='index-blabla-' + {% raw %} [[index]] {% endraw %}, placeholder="Бла бла", **{'v-model':'form.field'}) }}
```

Но так нельзя:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'
```

А как можно?

*P.S. Понимаю, что можно в JS коде получать поле, парсить его, изменять его атрибуты как требует задача, но это я оставлю на совсем крайний случай..*

Answer (score 1):

Друзья, меня осенило. Это в принципе невозможно, т.к. Jinja рендерит шаблон даже не зная о существовании Vue.
Т.е. Jinja - серверная технология, а Vue - клиентская..